# Uploading file using Web API and Azure server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-blob-storage

I'm currently trying to upload image using ASP web API and save it in my Azure server using [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2)

Then I took the request stream using `Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result` and send it to Azure using `blob.UploadFromStream(stream);`

The file got uploaded and when I fetch the URL it returns something like

http://testing.cloudapp.net:10000/devstoreaccount1/saveFiles/File_2_2.zip

I tried the link but it just returns a blank page.

Any idea why I can't download my uploaded file back?

Comment: Could you share how your uploading code looks like?

Comment: Hi Kiran, thanks for replying. But I've solved this problem myself, it turns out I should just use blob.UploadFile(fullPathFileName) instead of blob.UploadFromStream(stream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I should just use `blob.UploadFile(fullLocalPathFileName)` instead of `blob.UploadFromStream(stream)`. You can get the full local path of your file from the `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` and just send it easily to the blob.